# 6DOF Covariance projection for information filter and uncoupled dimensions

Tags: linear-algebra, kalman-filter

I am working on a Kalman filter to track a moving body. The state is tracked in position and velocity, with the state's covariance taking the form

\begin{bmatrix}
P_{x|x} & P_{x|y} & P_{x|z} & 0 & 0 & 0\\
P_{y|x} & P_{y|y} & P_{y|z} & 0 & 0 & 0\\
P_{z|x} & P_{z|y} & P_{z|z} & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & P_{vx|vx} & P_{vx|vy} & P_{vx|vz}\\
0 & 0 & 0 & P_{vy|vx} & P_{vy|vy} & P_{vy|vz}\\
0 & 0 & 0 & P_{vz|vx} & P_{vz|vy} & P_{vz|vz}
\end{bmatrix}

Notably, the diagonal 3x3 LL and UR being zero matrices imply, geometrically, that the position covariance of a given dimension isn't affected by the velocity and vice versa - this checks out as the uncertainty of where the tracked entity in the X dimension is unaffected by how fast it's moving in that, or any other, dimension.

During the prediction step, the covariance is projected in time with the state transition matrix $F$, defined as

\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & \Delta T & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & \Delta T & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & \Delta T\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1\\
\end{bmatrix}

With the covariance at instance $k$ defined as

$$P_{k|k-1} = F_k P_{k-1|k-1} F_k^T + Q_k$$

Properly verifying Q isn't a contributor to the forthcoming issue, the result is a $P_{k|k-1}$ that takes the form

\begin{bmatrix}
P_{x|x} & P_{x|y} & P_{x|z} & P_{x|vx} & P_{x|vy} & P_{x|vz}\\
P_{y|x} & P_{y|y} & P_{y|z} & P_{y|vx} & P_{y|vy} & P_{y|vz}\\
P_{z|x} & P_{z|y} & P_{z|z} & P_{z|vx} & P_{z|vy} & P_{z|vz}\\
P_{vx|x} & P_{vx|y} & P_{vx|z} & P_{vx|vx} & P_{vx|vy} & P_{vx|vz}\\
P_{vy|x} & P_{vy|y} & P_{vy|z} & P_{vy|vx} & P_{vy|vy} & P_{vy|vz}\\
P_{vz|x} & P_{vz|y} & P_{vz|z} & P_{vz|vx} & P_{vz|vy} & P_{vz|vz}
\end{bmatrix}

Or to state plainly, the process of projecting this, and many other matrices involved in the filter, causes the uncertainty/knowledge to "leak" into degrees of freedom that the system would otherwise be uncoupled from.

Is this behavior normal? I find this phenomenon doesn't "come out of the wash". This has unintended effects, such as causing an exponentially increasing error in the state (velocity estimates compound and skew the position estimates).

Comment: @user619894 Thank you, you are correct. I'm too deep into this code to remember things clearly it seems. The issue was actually with updating covariance matricies to the current step, and I've corrected my question (and verified that inversion is indeed producing block diagonals from block diagonals).

Comment: The behavior is definitely normal. That is because the "prediction" step of the Kalman filter uses the current estimate. That is, the current estimate of velocity is used to predict where the next position will be. Thus uncertainty about velocity propagates into uncertainty about position.

Comment: I understand that, I guess I just expected it to be constrained to the existing block diagonals - that is, the new position uncertainty being the previous position uncertainty plus velocity uncertainty times deltaT, rather than populating the off diagonal blocks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Researching further from zcsttn's comment to the question, it seems that my issue is not an error in the computation but a known limitation of the linear flavors of Kalman filters.

My specific use case is actually non-linear, while the $FPF^T$ propagation is specifically a linear transformation - the errors I'm seeing are the result of the inadequacy of the linear approximation of state and covariance evolution.

I don't know which direction I plan on moving from here, but flavors of filters lik the Unscented Kalman Filter specifically aim to improve these approximation errors at the cost of computation overhead.